# Repeat Recorded Macro

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have recorded one macro and want to apply in all the rows (Column S) at the same time it should keep changing the vlookup reference cell

Below is my recorded macro. Thanks in advance for your great support

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim I As Long

I = 2
    
    Do Until Cells(I, 9) = ""
        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-12],'Sheet3 (2)'!R2C1:R989C2,2,0)"
    Range("S2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("AD2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Sheet3 (2)").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A2:J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("M5").Select
    Sheets("Allocation").Select
    
    I = I + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking but formulaR1C1 is already design to be relative. So copying the same formula will update the row automatically.

Something like this is all you need to copy and paste all rows in column S.

```vb
Sub Macro5()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Intersect(Range("S:S"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        r.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-12],'Sheet3 (2)'!R2C1:R989C2,2,0)"
        r.Copy
        r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```